# what is the cleanest way to concat a const char * with a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I am aware that I can use a `stringstream` but I am hoping that there is a simpler way to write `"hello" + a_std_string_object` .

Comment: `"hello" + a_std_string_object` should work as written. Do you have a problem with it?

Comment: `a_std_string_object.insert(0, "hello");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an old/broken compiler it might require

```
string("hello") + std_string_object
```

but in modern compilers the natural code

```
"hello" + std_string_object
```

should work.

Comment: @Chad Ok, I've definitely used compilers in the past where the natural way didn't work. I never noticed it got fixed. It's not something that comes up often anyway.

Comment: `"hello" + std_string_object` has been valid since at least C++98. Perhaps you're thinking of adding a string literal with a `const char *`.

Comment: I'm thinking about g++ 2.95. That compiler made no pretensions to implement C++98 :)